# Count the number of matching suggested items in the DropDown portion of a ComboBox

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox

In my ComboBox I set:

- `datasource = [bindingsource]`
- `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`
- `AutoCompleteSource = ListItems`
- `AutoCompleteMode = Suggest`

How can I get the number of suggested items in the `DropDown` portion, after entering text in the ComboBox?

For example, I type "how" and the `DropDown` list suggests 5 matching items. How can I grab this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any property on the `ComboBox` control that gives you access to that information.

However, you should be able to do the same search against your ComboBox's DataSource that the `ComboBox` is doing internally, using a little LINQ:

```
var matches = comboBox1.Items.Cast<DataRowView>()
                       .Count(x => Convert.ToString(x["SomeColumn"])
                                          .StartsWith(comboBox1.Text))
```

Add the following `using` directive to the top of your class, if it's not there already:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String

Comment: It works! Thank you, and at the same time I am surprised that such property is not immediately available

Comment: Done. Sorry for that!